# Find all positive integer that $2^{2^n}+5 $ is a prime number.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Find all nonnegative integer that $2^{2^n}+5 $ is a prime number.

For $n=0$ we have $7$ - correct
For $n=1$ we have 9 - false
For $n=2$ we have 21 - false
For $n=3$ we have 259 ...

Maybe any ideas how to do it in general?

Comment: It's a duplicate, was asked just a couple of days ago. For $n \geqslant 1$, consider the remainder modulo $3$.

Comment: For n=3 its not 259, its 261 (256+5)

Answer (score 2):

For $n\ge1$

$$2\equiv-1\pmod3,2^{2^n}\equiv(-1)^{2^n}\equiv1\pmod3$$

$$2^{2^n}+5\equiv0\pmod3$$

For $n=3,2^{2^n}+5=261\ne259$